# How to delete or hide the 'Add' button from the 'Top' stack in backpack Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I want to hide the button `Add` button from the `Top` stack ? i tried `$this->crud->removeButton('create');` and `$this->crud->removeButtonFromStack('create', 'top');` but it's not working. I don’t want to use `$this->crud->denyAccess('create');` because this will cause me a problem when i'm updating. How can i hide the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I was adding `$this->crud->removeButton('create')` in `setup()` instead of `setupListOperation()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

$this->crud->denyAccess('create') or if it's more than two buttons make it an array i.e

$this->crud->denyAccess(['create', 'update', 'delete']);

Note: Everything should be inside your setup() i.e where your model is been registered